# how to get min and max rowcoun of a column for every row

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I would like to get max and min value in one row from one table

For example, I have the following rows in table a:

```
Insert into TABLE1
   (TRADE_DATE, COL_NAME, COL_VALUE, REC_COUNT)
 Values
   (TO_DATE('12/08/2011 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 'STOCK_SYM', 'A', 1210885);
Insert into TABLE1
   (TRADE_DATE, COL_NAME, COL_VALUE, REC_COUNT)
 Values
   (TO_DATE('12/08/2011 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 'STOCK_SYM', 'AA', 1211091);
Insert into TABLE1
   (TRADE_DATE, COL_NAME, COL_VALUE, REC_COUNT)
 Values
   (TO_DATE('12/08/2011 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 'STOCK_SYM', 'AAAA', 9);
Insert into TABLE1
   (TRADE_DATE, COL_NAME, COL_VALUE, REC_COUNT)
 Values
   (TO_DATE('12/08/2011 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 'STOCK_SYM', 'AAAE', 1);
Insert into TABLE1
   (TRADE_DATE, COL_NAME, COL_VALUE, REC_COUNT)
 Values
   (TO_DATE('12/08/2011 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 'STOCK_SYM', 'AABVF', 11);
Insert into TABLE1
   (TRADE_DATE, COL_NAME, COL_VALUE, REC_COUNT)
 Values
   (TO_DATE('12/08/2011 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 'STOCK_SYM', 'AAC', 916);
Insert into TABLE1
   (TRADE_DATE, COL_NAME, COL_VALUE, REC_COUNT)
 Values
   (TO_DATE('12/08/2011 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 'STOCK_SYM', 'AACAY', 2);
Insert into TABLE1
   (TRADE_DATE, COL_NAME, COL_VALUE, REC_COUNT)
 Values
   (TO_DATE('12/08/2011 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 'STOCK_SYM', 'AACC', 2469);
Insert into TABLE1
   (TRADE_DATE, COL_NAME, COL_VALUE, REC_COUNT)
 Values
   (TO_DATE('12/08/2011 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 'STOCK_SYM', 'AACOU', 66);
```

i would like to get the results as below

```
col_val1 max_val     col_val2    min_val
-------- -------     --------    ------
AA       1211091     AAAE        1
A        1210885     AACAY       2
AACC     2496        AAAA        9
AAC      916         AABVF       11
AACOU    66          AACOW       56
```

I tried `min(col_value) over (partition by trade_date order by rec_count)` but I only can get either min or max. When I create two tables, one with min and another with max, and select from it, I get a Cartesian join.

Comment: Your sample data doesn't have any repeating values within the "col_val" column. Would there be more than one AA in the real data for a day ?

Comment: In your sample result, what are the max and min values for? Is it per date? Your sample input data has one date only...

Answer (score 3):

This returns the result expect. You should note that if there's an odd number of results the bottom row will have identical values for col_val1 and col_val2

```
WITH data as (   
   SELECT  
            row_number() over (order by rec_count desc) rn_desc,
            row_number() over (order by rec_count asc) rn_asc,
            trade_date,
            COL_NAME,
            col_value,
            rec_count
            
   FROM TAble1) 
SELECT 
    d1.col_value col_val1,
    d1.rec_count max_val,
    d2.col_value col_val2,
    d2.rec_count min_val
FROM
    data d1
    INNER JOIN data d2
    ON d1.rn_desc = d2.rn_asc
WHERE 
    d1.rn_desc <= (select CEIL(COUNT(*)/2) FROM data)
```

You can see a working example at this [data.se query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/2296/sample-for-8568394). (Note there are some minor difference in the translation to SQL Server syntax most notably in `CEILING` vs `CEIL` )

Answer (score 2):

I think you may need to

```
select col_val, rec_count, 
       row_number over (partition by trade_date order by rec_count DESC) as HiLoRow
```

for the first 2 columns in your answer, then

```
select col_val, rec_count, 
       row_number over (partition by trade_date order by rec_count ) as LoHiRow
```

for the second half.
Then select from both these, nested, and join on HiLoRow = LoHiRow

Things may still not be ideal if two col_vals have the same rec_count.
The list will also be twice as long as you need so you might want something like

```
where q1.rec_count >= q2.rec_count
```

to halve the length.